# How to delete a Litmus account

Tags: account-management, litmus

How can I permanently delete/cancel my [Litmus](https://litmus.com) account? I can’t find any info on how to completely delete my account.

Comment: I searched for an answer and all I got was an article in their help center on how to [cancel the subscription](http://litmus.com/help/accounts/cancel-subscription/). Nothing on how to delete the account. So +1 to question.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I found that article as well, but it clearly says “_Your account will still be accessible after cancellation._”, ergo my question.

Comment: Try this link I have the same problem https://litmus.com/orders/169234/cancellations/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up contacting their support and asking for a complete deletion of the account.

Answer (score -1):

What I did was:

- Create a disposable address in Yahoo!.
- Edit Litmus profile (https://litmus.com/identity/edit) and change my email address to the Yahoo disposable address
- Confirm the email-address-change request in Yahoo's inbox
- Then delete the disposable Yahoo! address

Comment: This doesn't delete/cancel the account, just make it harder to recover access to it.